# Finding the common increase term in a non-constant sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence which I can't seem to properly map.

$a \; ; \;a +\frac{1}{2} a \; ; \; a + \frac{1}{2} a +\frac{1}{4} a$ + ...

I'm basically trying to write an R function that will calculate the result for any step in the sequence. I understand that the change is essentially $\frac{1}{2^n}$, but I haven't managed to factor it in so that I can get the result instead of just the change at every step.
For example, if $a = 100$, and I run the sequence 3 times, I would like to obtain a formula that yields: $100\; ; \;150 \; ; \;175$

Any idea how I can obtain the general formula for this?

Comment: With $c=1/2$ this is $a, (1+c)a, (1+c+c^2)a, \ldots$. Now lookup “geometric sum formula”

Comment: Thank you! Getting to the reason was apparently what hindered me so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any step

$$s_n=s_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}a$$

So that

$$s_n=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\right)a$$

Let $S:= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{k}}$. Observe that this is the geometric series of reason $q=\frac{1}{2}$. Then

$S=1+\frac{1}{2}(S-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})$

$\frac{1}{2}S=1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}$

so

$S=2(1-\frac{1}{2^n})$

Then

$$s_n= 2(1-\frac{1}{2^n})a$$

Comment: Thank you! I was really struggling to determine the reason and plug it in the formula.

Comment: @James you’re welcome 